# Retrieve Hex or RGB values from Bootswatch theme via python/dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am currently creating a dashboard using dash with figures using plotly. I am using the bootswatch themes (https://bootswatch.com/) with bootstrap components to style the dashboard and I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve the primary, secondary, success etc. colours into either RGB or HEX so that I don't have to hard code it in and can then parse these into plotly functions to style the graphs in the same theme.

Answer (score 2):

As of writing this there isn't a way to do it with Python only.

A dash bootstrap components theme is just a uri pointing to a stylesheet.

```
>>> dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

For the stylesheets in `external_stylesheets` `link` elements are generated and added to the document.

So there isn't a property on a theme or on the app that holds the value of the css variables.

---

A workaround solution is to use [`clientside callbacks`](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks):

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Store(id="intermediate-store"), dcc.Store(id="color-store")])

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(val) {
        const bodyStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
        return {
            primary: bodyStyles.getPropertyValue("--primary"),
            secondary: bodyStyles.getPropertyValue("--secondary"),
            success: bodyStyles.getPropertyValue("--success"),
        };
    }
    """,
    Output("intermediate-store", "data"),
    Input("intermediate-store", "data"),
)


@app.callback(
    Output("color-store", "data"),
    Input("intermediate-store", "data"),
)
def update_output_div(data):
    # data equals: {'primary': '#007bff', 'secondary': '#6c757d', 'success': '#28a745'}
    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

So the idea in the code above is to use Javascript in clientside callbacks to retrieve the css variables and store them in an intermediate [`Store`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store). When it's stored we can use another callback to retrieve the value as a dictionary and do something with it.

You could use it by setting a variable when the second callback is triggered or you could use `State("color-store", "data")` in other callbacks.